# Airflow running spark submit task through for loop --- Values are not being iterated

Tags: airflow

I am trying to loop through a list and pass the values of the list as parameter to my spark-submit job in Airflow. The first value is being passed but the job ends with the first value of loop only. The whole list is not being iterated .

```
list_of_val=['first_value','second_value','third_value']

for val in list_of_val:
    spark_submit_local = SparkSubmitOperator(
            task_id='sample-spark-job',
            conn_id='spark_default',
            application='path-to-my-jar/job.jar',
            application_args=[
                    '-e', val],
            java_class='com.test.sample.job.SparkSubmitjob',
            dag=dag,
            schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *'
    )
```

So as per the logs the spark submit job is triggered with the val value being passed as first_value, rest values are not passed or iterated.
Am I missing something here?? Any pointer on this will help.

Thanks
Ashit

Comment: Try `application_args=['-e'] + list_of_val` instead? Currently you are making 3 spark tasks, each with 1 arg from list, but all tasks have same task_id so I think only 1 will run.

Comment: @Hitobat Thanks this gives me an idea if because of task_id being same 3 separate tasks are not being spawned so i can change the task id dynamically. I think this will work . Will try and update.